# Using R to run multiple regression modeling when one of the categorical variables has several levels

Tags: multiple-regression, interpretation, many-categories

I am looking at a dataset that looks like this. Let's call it `movies`:

[image]

As you can see, the `genre` column has several values. So does the `studio` column. I am trying to determine what the multiple linear regression model is using R using these two variables and the `avg_score` column. How do I do this? I tried

[image]

But that spits out this data:

[image]

But that doesn't seem right? First off... if the movie is made from Studio A, that means it can't be made from Studio B. Also, if a movie is a horror movie, it's not a documentary. How do I capture that relationship using MLR and R? The output I generated seems wrong no?

For example, let's look at `studio7th art`. Is the way to interpret that row that it has a coefficient of 15.68 (If the studio is made by them, the `avg_score` on avg goes up 15.68), with a p-value of 0.44 (not significant), with a SE of 20? That data seems... worthless. Is there a way to do this that isn't idiotic?

Answer (score 4):

"if the movie is made from Studio A, that means it can't be made from Studio B." - That is implicit in how the variables were created. What internally happens is that R is creating dummy variables from your catgorical variable.

In any given record, only 1 of the dummy variables will have a value of 1, while all else will be 0.

"For example, let's look at studio7th art." - If the co-efficient in a regression shows a high p-value it could mean multiple different things. In your case, the biggest problem is that you have a large number of levels for studio and probably not enough observations in your dataset to characterize every level.

So rather than build a model with all studios, you could build dummy variables yourself. Something along the lines of "Studio-Category1" which includes some of the larger houses. "Studio-Category2" with smaller studios etc, which you would know from domain experience.

Subsequently build your model with these variables as inputs instead of the entire studio categories.

Comment: +1 Moreover it seems that the dataset has not been cleaned at all since you can see `20th Century Fox Corporat` and `20th Century Fox Corporation` (or `Anchor Bay Films` `Anchor Bay Entertainment`), I would assume those are the same studio but here since the name are slightly different R consider them two different studios (and the headcount for those studios is even lower than it should be)

Comment: So I guess R knows how to turn a single column into several dummy variables if it notices that the column is categorical and the values are mutually exclusive? What does it use as a reference/starting value of variable?

Comment: You should read up on dummy variables, it should clear up your doubts.